# How to keep world anchor in a AR WebGL application developed in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, webgl, augmented-reality, unity-webgl

I'm using Zappar Plugin to develop an AR application in Unity. I'm using Zappar Image Tracker, which allows me show a mesh when I point the camera to a specific image target. My problem is when I stop point the camera to the image target, the acnhor of the world seems to change, and the mesh disappear. So I want to know if there is a way to keep this initial anchor after the camera stops point to the image target, and also keep the mesh visible and stable. Has anyone ever used this plugin and know how to help me? Thanks!